# Why does the table handle text-overflow different in chrome than in firefox?

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, firefox, angular-material

I have the same Anuglar (mat-table) html running in chrome and firefox. While Chrome has a scrollbar to scroll the table cell, Firefox overlaps text

```
    <td
      style="
        min-width: 160px;
        max-width: 400px;
        text-overflow: clip;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
      "
      mat-cell
      *matCellDef="let element"
    >
```

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox
[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre], preferably using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), so that others can reproduce the situation. It would also be good to tell us the versions of the browsers used, and on what platforms.

Answer (score 5):

(**Multiple edits**) I can confirm this is a bug, I found a relevant link that describes the issue which is yet to be resolved, although I had initially suspected that it could be a different interpretation of CSS standards between the two browser engines:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=221154

The solution to your problem, however, would be to insert a `div` element *inside* the table cell and limit *that* to a specific `max-width` to get the result you are expecting.

```
td div {
  max-width:400px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

Here is a sample with a working fiddle - the issue you are describing is clearly reflected in the example fiddle if you open it with Firefox, while on Chrome it works differently.

https://jsfiddle.net/4r01otfk/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem but after a lot of searching I found out one thing. First, I will tell you something about [the Angular source](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) site itself, and then I will tell you about the possible problem.

Angular supports most recent browsers. This includes the following specific versions:

[image]

**But to solve the problem, you have to enable polyfills**

Angular is built on the latest standards of the web platform. Targeting such a wide range of browsers is challenging because they do not support all features of modern browsers. You compensate by loading polyfill scripts ("polyfills") for the browsers you must support. See instructions on how to include polyfills in your project below.

**Enabling polyfills with CLI projects**

The Angular CLI provides support for polyfills. If you are not using the CLI to create your projects, see Polyfill instructions for [non-CLI users](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#non-cli).

The `polyfills` options of the browser and test builder can be a full path for a file (Example: `src/polyfills.ts`) or, relative to the current workspace or module specifier (Example: `zone.js`).

If you create a TypeScript file, make sure to include it in the files property of your `tsconfig file`.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ]
  ...
}
```

The npm packages for the mandatory polyfills (such as `zone.js`) were installed automatically for you when you created your project and their corresponding import statements are ready to go. You probably won't touch these.

But if you need an optional `polyfill`, you'll have to install its npm package. **For example**, if you need **the web animations polyfill**, you could install it with npm, using the following command (or the yarn equivalent):

```
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

**Note:** that the web-animations.js polyfill is only here as an example, it isn't a strict requirement for angular anymore.

**Then** open the `polyfills.ts` file and un-comment the corresponding import statement as in the following example:

```
//polyfills.ts

import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

If you can't find the polyfill you want in `polyfills.ts`, add it yourself, following the same pattern:

```
install the npm package

import the file in polyfills.ts
```

These are the polyfills required to run an Angular application on each supported browser:

[image]

for extra details, you can check this [link](https://www.w3resource.com/angular/browser-support.php).